# Find path with sum of numbers is maximum

Tags: c++

I'm trying to find path with sum of numbers is maximum. It's only allowed to move right and down through the matrix.
I've coded it but it doesn't give me the maximum sum, and I can't figure out why it does so!. 
Thanks in advance.

Here's my code

```
 /*Given grid of positive numbers, strat from (0,0) ad end at (n,n).
   Move only to RIGHT and DOWN. Find path with sum of numbers is maximum. */

 #include<iostream>
 using namespace std;

 int grid[2][3] = { { 5, 1, 2 }, { 6, 7, 8 } };


 int max(int x, int y){
     if (x >= y){
        return x;
     }
     else if (x < y){
        return y;
     }

 }
 bool valid(int r, int c){
     if (r + 1 == 2 || c + 1 == 3)
          return false;
     else
          return true;
 }
 int maxPathSum(int row, int column){

    if (!valid(row, column))
       return 0;

 if (row == 1 && column == 2) //base condition
       return grid[row][column];

 int path1 = maxPathSum(row, column + 1); //Right
 int path2 = maxPathSum(row + 1, column); //Down

 return grid[row][column] + max(path1, path2);
}


int main()
{
    cout << maxPathSum(0, 0) << endl;
    return 0; 

}
```

the correct answer should be 26, but the output is 6.

Comment: add `cout` statements to figure out where your code is going and why it isnt working

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the program, line by line, in a debugger to see what's really going on?

Comment: And no need to make your own `max` function, the [standard library already have one](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max).

Comment: Your "base condition" seems hacky..

Comment: I traced it on paper and it should work fine. but it doesn't.

Comment: Trace it in a debugger.

Comment: Your is valid condition is wrong. I suggest you use `cout`s or a debugger and figure it out for yourself.

Comment: I debugged it. The problem was the is valid condition. you are right. Thank you(Y). Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `Valid` should be

```
bool valid (int r, int c)
{
    return r < 2 && c < 3;
}
```

and then you got `26` ([Live example](http://ideone.com/UWOEPD)).

BTW, you may use dynamic programming for this problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use dynamic programming to solve the problem

Here is the code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int grid[2][3] = { { 5, 1, 2 }, { 6, 7, 8 } };

int dp[3][4];

int main()
{
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        dp[0][i] = 0;

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        dp[i][0] = 0;

    for(int i=1;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(int j=1;j<4;j++)
        {
            dp[i][j] = grid[i-1][j-1] + max(dp[i][j-1], dp[i-1][j]);
        }
    }

    cout << dp[2][3];
    return 0;
}
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/6oGVah)

Comment: Aha, Thank you for solving it using dynamic programming (Y).

Answer (score -1):

Apart from DP, you can also use simple (n,m) Matrix based solution. The good part is this approach wont need recursion as DP does which can cause memory issues if matrix is bigger and space complexity is just O(n x m) i.e. input array itself. And the time complexity is also O(n x m). Following code in java illustrate the approach -

```
package com.company.dynamicProgramming;

import static java.lang.Integer.max;

public class MaxSumPathInMatrix {

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int mat[][] = { { 10,  10, 2, 0,  20, 4 },
                        { 1,   0,  0, 30, 2,  5 },
                        { 200, 10, 4, 0,  2,  0 },
                        { 1,   0,  2, 20, 0,  4 }
        };

        System.out.println(findMaxSum2(mat));
    }


    /*
      Given a matrix of N * M. Find the maximum path sum in matrix.
      Find the one path having max sum - originating from (0,0) with traversal to either right or down till (N-1, M-1)
    */
    static int findMaxSum2(int mat[][])
    {
        int M = mat[0].length;
        int N = mat.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
            {
                if(i==0 && j!=0){
                    mat[i][j]+=mat[i][j-1];
                }
                else if(i!=0 && j==0){
                    mat[i][j]+=mat[i-1][j];
                }
                else if (i!=0 && j!=0){
                    mat[i][j]+= max(mat[i-1][j], mat[i][j-1]);
                }
            }
        }
        return mat[N-1][M-1];
    }

}
```

Run it as -

```
251

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Further Even if you are using Dynamic Programming(DP) then use Memoization concept  to reduce the time complexity.. Here is the code with DP plus memoization along  complexity calculation -

```
package com.company.dynamicProgramming;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import static java.lang.Integer.max;

public class MaxSumPathInMatrix {

    static int complexity = 0;

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int mat[][] = { { 10,  10, 2, 0,  20, 4 },
                        { 1,   0,  0, 30, 2,  5 },
                        { 200, 10, 4, 0,  2,  0 },
                        { 1,   0,  2, 20, 0,  4 }
        };

        System.out.println("Max Sum : " + findMaxSum2_dp(mat, 0, 0, new HashMap<>()));
        System.out.println("Time complexity : " +complexity);
    }

    /*
     ~~~> solve via ~dp~ and ~memoization~
     Given a matrix of N * M. Find the maximum path sum in matrix.
     Find the one path having max sum - originating from (0,0) with traversal to either right or down till (m-1, n-1)
    */
    static int findMaxSum2_dp(int mat[][], int i, int j, Map<String, Integer> memo){

        int M = mat[0].length;
        int N = mat.length;

        Integer sum = memo.get(i+"-"+j);
        if(sum!= null){
            return sum;
        }

        complexity++;

        if(i==N-1 && j<M-1){
            mat[i][j] += findMaxSum2_dp(mat, i, j+1, memo);
            memo.put(i+"-"+j, mat[i][j]);
            return mat[i][j];
        }
        else if(i<N-1 && j==M-1){
            mat[i][j] += findMaxSum2_dp(mat, i+1, j, memo);
            memo.put(i+"-"+j, mat[i][j]);
            return mat[i][j];
        }
        else if (i<N-1 && j<M-1){
            int s1 = findMaxSum2_dp(mat, i+1, j, memo);
            int s2 = findMaxSum2_dp(mat, i, j+1, memo);
            mat[i][j] += max(s1, s2);
            memo.put(i+"-"+j, mat[i][j]);
            return mat[i][j];
        }

        return mat[N-1][M-1] += max(mat[N-1][M-2], mat[N-2][M-1]);

    }

}
```

Two important points to note in above code -

1. I am storing max sum of any sub matrix [i][j] in a store(HashMap), whenever it's max sum is ready. And in further steps if this sub matrix [i][j] reappears then I take it from store instead of processing again. As a illustration - you can see [N-1][M-1] appears 2 times in below diagram of recursion -

```
                            [N][M] = max([N][M-1]) , [N-1][M]
                                  /                  \
                                 /                    \
                                /                      \
   [N][M-1] = max ([N-1][M-1], [N][M-2])            [N-1][M] = max ([N-2][M], [N-1][M-1])
```

2. Connected with Point 1 : I have provisioned a complexity variable which I increment if I have to calculate max sum for matrix [i][j] i.e. wont find in the store. If you see the result it shows 25 in 6x4 matrix i.e. the time complexity is just O(NxM).